# Navigate to file folder ZSH

Tags: zsh

I really like the `oh my zsh` feature that allows you to navigate to the folder that contains a file. I don't know if it's a plugin or a configuration.

I've been testing the following settings but haven't found it:

```
setopt auto_name_dirs
setopt auto_cd
setopt cdable_vars
setopt pushd_ignore_dups
setopt auto_pushd
```

The idea is to drag and drop a file to the terminal app (in mac) and then navigate to its folder, but without using `oh my zsh`. Do anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76227/how-to-make-cd-dir-filename-take-me-to-dir

I've added this function to my `.zshrc`:

```
cd() {
    if [ -d "$1" ] || [ -z "$1" ]; then
        builtin cd "$@"
    else
        builtin cd "${1%/*}"
    fi
}
```

and it's working